# Can't import any Firebase classes

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Out of nowhere, I suddenly can no longer import or use any Firebase classes. The class names show up in intellisense, but when hitting tab to import, it inserts their fully qualified name, and an error in the class name.

**build.gradle (app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.opticalgenesis.lbp.dogg"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 'P'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha16'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url="https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**small snippet**

```
 private fun setupModel() {
        val builder = com.google.firebase.ml.custom.model.FirebaseModelDownloadConditions.Builder()
    }
```

FirebaseModelDownloadConditions is not the only class that doesn't import, they all don't.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you seemed to be using the new namespace for androidx, do you have jetifier enabled?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque yes, android.enableJetifier and android.useAndroidX are both set to true in gradle.properties